# Appengine search API doesn't work for deploys in flex environment

Tags: google-app-engine

I have been trying to deploy a service that uses the appengine golang search APIs. It works fine if I deploy it with `vm: true` option, but it's getting deprecated. When I deploy it with `env: flex`, I get this error:

`service bridge HTTP failed: Post http://appengine.googleapis.internal:10001/rpc_http: dial tcp: lookup appengine.googleapis.internal on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host`

How can I get around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sadly Search API is not available on AppEngine Flex anymore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/migrating#search).It was available on AppEngine Flex using the compat runtime, but as you said, this is deprecated and will stop working on October 27th, 2017.

I guess you have two options:

- use something like ElasticSearch (either SaaS or using Compute Engine to create your own cluster),
- use an AppEngine Standard service to handle the search part of your application.

Comment: Do you know if there is a plan to upgrade the go version for the appengine standard service ? Seems it's still on go 1.6 and the package vendoring doesn't work for me for the deploy time build. Also, do you know why it's not getting supported in the flex environment?

Comment: @JianliangZhao sadly both of your questions are related to Google Cloud roadmap which I don't have access to (I am not a Google employee). From my experience working with GCP, it's not a good idea to use an Alpha or Beta product without having a plan B. [You can try to open ticket for your issues](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers), but if your project is a Business product, you shouldn't count on it. You may have better guidance by buying a GCP support package (if your main business uses GCP, you can't really avoid that).

Comment: I have the option to use Appengine Standard service. Thanks for all the information!